# How to inherit from UserIdentity with the least work possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a class hierarchy inheriting from `IdentityUser`, i'm wondering what i need to do if "nothing" on my hierarchy aside from what is already defined in `IdentityUser` relates to authentication?

Can i just inherit from it and create the objects while still using

```
            .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
```

Or will it not work when my users are a subtype of `IdentityUser` even if i'm not using any of their properties to authenticate?

I don't really have a leaf node as the hierarchy of users branches so i can't really use the lowest class.

Answer (score 1):

As i couldn't find an exemple online (they all show how to use a custom user type, not a hierarchy) i tried and dug around the code some.

Aparently there is no problem with using any object inherited from the IdentityUser (or whichever class was specified as the user in `AddDefaultIdentity`.

When attempting to create a user passing an object that inherit from that class will create the appropriate object in database (the object isn't casted in the `UserManager.CreateAsync` but added to the context with a simple add on the context itself, not on a typed DBSet).

The relevant code can be found in the source code of UserStore : https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/EF/UserStore.cs line 165, we can see there is a simple

```
Context.Add(user);
```

Letting EF core create the appropriate discriminator in the DB.

So overall, if no customization of authentication/identity is required and there is only a need to add more information to the user, having a hierarchy of users seems to work fine and leaving the default `UserIdentity` class declared in the services does not pose any issues.

I have not yet tested if it poses issues retrieving the user through the UserManager as it's not required for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

> > Can i just inherit from it and create the objects while still using

You should register the new object when adding the identity service.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

We usually extend the `IdentityUser` to involve custom properties for user :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: But i don't have an ApplicationUser, instead i have a large hierarchy of user subtypes, so i can't do AddDefaultIdentity<T> because it's really AddDefaultIdentity<A or B or C or D or E or F or G all of which inherit from IdentityUser>. Hence why i'm wondering if it's safe to use identityuser there even if i'm actually using subtypes down the road. I've done some testing in the meantype and it seems to work (i pass in types that are lower in the inheritance chain to CreateUserAsync that expects a IdentityUser and my whole object does seem to be created)